# ASP.NET Core 3.0 - Can't Update-Database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I just created the project using the command `dotnet new angular -o <output_directory_name> -au Individual` and scaffold identity then I installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer but when I run the command update-database, I get the error below.

```
Failed executing DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [AspNetRoles] (
    [Id] TEXT NOT NULL,
    [Name] TEXT(256) NULL,
    [NormalizedName] TEXT(256) NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp] TEXT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);
```

and then at the end end another error

> Error Number:2716,State:1,Class:16
>   Column, parameter, or variable #2: Cannot specify a column width on data type text.

Below is the generated `CreateIdentitySchema` migration

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "AspNetRoles",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
        Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
        NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
        ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
    });
```

**ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.cs**

```
modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole", b =>
{
    b.Property<string>("Id")
        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(450)");

    b.Property<string>("ConcurrencyStamp")
        .IsConcurrencyToken()
        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

    b.Property<string>("Name")
        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(256)")
        .HasMaxLength(256);

    b.Property<string>("NormalizedName")
        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(256)")
        .HasMaxLength(256);

    b.HasKey("Id");

    b.HasIndex("NormalizedName")
        .IsUnique()
        .HasName("RoleNameIndex")
        .HasFilter("[NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL");

    b.ToTable("AspNetRoles");
});
```

How to fix this errors so I can update-database?

Changing 'TEXT' to 'VARCHAR' in **00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema.Designer.cs** resulted in the following error. The same happens when I change it to 'NVARCHAR'

```
Data type 'VARCHAR' for property 'Id' is not supported in this form. Either specify the length explicitly in the type name, for example as 'NVARCHAR(16)', or remove the data type and use APIs such as HasMaxLength to allow EF choose the data type.
```

Comment: Use varchar(256) instead of your text(256); don't use text for your id, use varchar with appropriate length

Comment: @sepupic I've updated my question. I didn't create the migration it was generated when I created the project. It uses <string>

Comment: @PeterSmith I created the project using dotnet new angular -o <output_directory_name> -au Individual Everything was generated by visual studio. Everything worked in another project, the only difference is the I've scaffold the identity on this one.

Comment: The problem is that the  migration is generating SQL `TEXT` fields, which don't have a size, instead of `nvarchar`, which do.

Answer (score 14):

I had this error and it can be fixed as follows.

1. Open up the project and delete 2 migration files and 1 snapshot file.  Most likely named 0000...InitialCreate.cs, 0000...InitialCreate.Designer.cs and the ...DbContextModelSnapshot.cs. Leave the DbContextClass.
2. Delete the database.
3. Use dotnet to create a new migration and update the database.  I also script the migration to check it.

`dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --context ApplicationDbContext -v`

`dotnet ef database update --context ApplicationDbContext -v`

`dotnet ef migrations script --context ApplicationDbContext -v`

Comment: Thanks @abC Sharp -  one minor tweak to step 3 I had to make was to add a project option.  For example, using my custom DbContext:                              dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --context IdentityContext -v --project MSC.CodeGenHero.MVC

Comment: After deleting the files mentioned, you can follow Microsoft documentation for installing necessary tools, creating the migration, and creating database and schema at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?msclkid=cd2a4acfbdc111ec86f5eb50f88dc714&tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Answer (score 8):

These answers were all helpful, especially the one from @klent. I had generated a new project using:

> dotnet new angular -o [MY PROJECT] -au Individual

This produced a new project that used Sqlite as the data provider, although I wasn't aware of that. I changed the connection string to my SQL Server, then ran:

> dotnet ef database update

and got the error posted in the original question. After reviewing the answers here I realized that I had the incorrect data provider, and the migrations were targeting Sqlite syntax, which was using TEXT(256) for one of the column specifications. So my specific steps to correct were to:

1. Remove the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite Nuget package.
2. Install the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Nuget package.
3. In the ConfigureServices method of my Startup.cs, change the `services.AddDbContext` call to use `options.UseSqlServer` instead of `options.UseSqlite`.
4. Remove the _CreateIdentitySchema and ApplicationDbContentsModelSnapshot classes from the Migrations folder.
5. After ensuring the connection string in AppSettings.json points to the SQL Server and not Sqlite, run `dotnet ef migrations add CreateIdentitySchema -o Data\Migrations`. Note that the output folder specified in the `-o` parameter may be different for you.
6. Check the Visual Studio Project Explorer. Two new classes should now appear in the Migrations folder.
7. Run `dotnet ef database update`. This will create the tables in the database noted in the connection string.

Additionally, if you want your tables to be in a specific schema, for example "Auth", open your ApplicationDbContext class and add:

```csharp
protected override void OnModelCreating( ModelBuilder builder )
{
    base.OnModelCreating( builder );
    builder.HasDefaultSchema( "Auth" );
}
```

However, this will set the schema for all access that uses this DbContext. It wasn't a problem for me since I'm not using EF for my application data, just Identity data. YMMV.

Comment: Thank you.  This worked for me.  The original migration that came with the template was targeting SQLite (hence `TEXT(256)`).  I removed it and regenerated the initial migration targeting SQL Server and it became `nvarchar(256)`.

Comment: Still relevant! Very helpful.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. Been pulling my hair out for a few hours and this fixed it in a few minutes. Nice easy instructions too :)

Answer (score 4):

As already answered by a few others the default Identity installation seems to create the wrong column types; namely that some of the Id columns should be varchar and not text.

I had exactly the same issues as you and spent ages trying to effectively solve it.

The quickest way I found to solve it, and for anyone else coming across this problem, is to:

- Create the new project
- Delete the Migrations folder completely
- Install the package for Sql Server (Or whatever data system you're using) and connection string details
- Add your own migration using `dotnet ef migrations add <MIGRATION NAME>` or `Add-Migration` (this will write new migration designer files from scratch with the correct column structure
- Lastly, update your database with `dotnet ef database update` or `Update-Database`

Comment: This did not work for me. VS still created wrong column types when I run command `Add-Migration`

Comment: This actually worked for me, the new migrations contained the correct code to create the DB on SQLServer

Answer (score 1):

As per comments from @sepupic and @PeterSmith, the problem was that the auto-generated code in `00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema.Designer.cs` had `TEXT` fields with `HasMaxLength` so I changed it to `VARCHAR` then I added `HasMaxLength(450)` to all `VARCHAR` Ids then I tried to update-database again and it worked.

I run the project and tried to Register a user and I got the error below

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Bolean'

Since I still had errors I did the following:

1. I deleted the generated table then created a new project with the command `dotnet new angular -o <output_directory_name> -au Individual`
2. I didn't scaffold new identity to the newly created project
3. I copied the db name from my previous project and run the command update-database
4. There were two missing tables `DeviceCodes` and `PersistedGrants` so I run the command `add-migration` but it didn't generate anything so I copied the migration code of the two tables from my previous project and pasted it the empty migration code I created earlier.
5. I run the project again and register a new user and it finally worked

I still don't know why I got errors since the project I did before didn't have any problem with the auto-generated code.

Answer (score 0):

I had an error like yours as

> Column 'Id' in table 'Roles' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.

Because I changed the table names those are coming with Individual Identity of Asp.Net Core web application.

To put it simply,

- Delete everything in Migrations Folder apart from **ApplicationDBContext**.
- **Add-Migration**
- Make sure if your tables names are matching in **Up**, **Down** and **BuildTargetModel**
- Then **update-database**

It worked for me!

**Edit :** My main point is that make sure if your tables names are matching in Up, Down and BuildTargetModel. After that **update-database** will work.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this database update error with the first answer by @abCsharp, but not until I noticed that the project, which I started with the option of Identity, had created a new migrations folder under the project folder. The original migrations folder was under a Data folder that also contained the ApplicationDbContext.

I deleted the original folder (for cleanliness) and ran the newly created migration which worked. I also deleted the migrations history table in the database, which contains tables for which I am not using migrations.

FWIW All the data types for text in all the tables are nvarchar.